# Samba share not working

Tags: 20.04, smb

I am unable to mount a SMB share in Ubuntu 20.04 receiving an error 2?
any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Smb is used to share a  folder from what? Another ubuntu machine, windows, router..? There have historically been problems if the two are using different versions of smb.

Comment: The mounted folder is coming from a NAS

Comment: I added this line to the file no effect on the error

Comment: Check the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229929/cant-acces-nas-anymore-after-upgrading-to-20-04
No solution works with NAS share in 20.04. 
With full samba, I can mount the NAS share but every objects (jp, avi, etc.) is treated as folder.

Answer (score 4):

Add "client min protocol = NT1" to /etc/samba/smb.conf in [global] section

It is required to access NAS which only support SMB v1 with the new Samba v4.11.6 included in Ubuntu 20.04. [Samba 4.11.x disables by default SMB v1](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.11.0.html).

You will probably need [the fix for this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1872476) to be published in main Ubuntu repository, as pointed by Opifex.

Comment: Check the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229929/cant-acces-nas-anymore-after-upgrading-to-20-04, these solutions don't work for NAS share.
General file and folder sharing works well in 20.04. I t's a NAS share specific problem.

Comment: What makes you think it's NAS specific? 
It's a bug in samba that has been fixed in the meanwhile: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476 (still needs to the release though)

Comment: I guessed because SMB1 has disappeared else where and it was confirmed by OP : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234460/samba-share-not-working/1234496?noredirect=1#comment2078890_1234460

The fix you point is needed but does not enables SMB1 access.

Comment: This works, and is necessary. It needs to be an easy opt-out (or opt-in on first use). The Ubuntu camp is often at the mercy of upstream developers, and their target demographic seems to have changed. Bottom line: It is a larger security issue for me that I cannot connect than it is to use an older protocol.